# Show that $|z^x|$ is equal to the principal value of $|z|^x$.

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you show that $|z^x|$ is equal to the principal value of $|z|^x$?

The definition of exponentiation in $\mathbb{C}$ is $z^x:=e^{x\log z}$, while the definition of logarithms in $\mathbb{C}$ is $\log z:=\ln |z| + i \arg z$. So what I need to do is to show that

$|z^x|=|e^{x(\ln|z|+i\arg z)}|$ is equal to the principal value (i.e., $\arg z \in (-\pi,\pi]$) of $|z|^x=e^{x(\ln|z|+\arg |z|)}$.

I have no idea how to do this. Any hint will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think it is there already, in what you did. Observe only that the part $\;i\arg z\;$ already assumes one has chosen a branch (principal value or whatever):

$$\left|z^x\right|=\left|\left(e^{x\log|z|+ix\arg z}\right)\right|=e^{x\log|z|}=|z|^x$$